# A holomorphic shrinking of a domain into a compact subset

Tags: fa.functional-analysis, gn.general-topology, gt.geometric-topology, cv.complex-variables

This question is related to [these](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/331172/a-continuous-bi-lipschitz-shrinking-of-a-domain-into-a-compact-subset) [two](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/354304/density-of-continuous-functions-to-interior-in-set-of-all-continuous-functions/354358#354358).

Let $X\subset \mathbb{C}^{n}$ be a bounded domain. I am interested in the following **property**: there is a sequence of continuous maps $\varphi_n:\overline{X}\to X$ which are holomorphic on $X$ and such that $\varphi_n(x)\to x$, for every $x \in X$. Every convex domain has this property.

> If $n=1$ is this **property** equivalent to $X$ being a Jordan domain?

> If $n>1$ and $X$ is pseudoconvex what are some sufficient conditions on $X$ (other than convexity) so that it has this **property**?

Comment: Can you explain what $\phi(x)$ is?

Comment: @AlexandreEremenko it was just an error, sorry

Comment: I guess it holds also for images of biholomorphic maps from the closed bounded starshaped domains into \mathbb{C}^n.